# Can't find package building go-ethereum

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, go-ethereum

I am new to golang and I am compiling the go-ethereum. But it gave me some errors which I can't find the solution searching google. This is weird because it seems that only me has this problem.

This is my environment

```golang
export GOROOT=/usr/local/go
export GOPATH=/home/sam/go
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin

sam@ubuntu:~/work/blockchain/go-ethereum$ go version
go version go1.12.7 linux/amd64
```

And this is the error

```golang
sam@ubuntu:~/work/blockchain/go-ethereum$ make all
build/env.sh go run build/ci.go install
internal/build/azure.go:25:2: cannot find package "github.com/Azure/azure-storage-blob-go/azblob" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/github.com/Azure/azure-storage-blob-go/azblob (from $GOROOT)
    /home/sam/work/blockchain/go-ethereum/build/_workspace/src/github.com/Azure/azure-storage-blob-go/azblob (from $GOPATH)
build/ci.go:61:2: cannot find package "github.com/cespare/cp" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/github.com/cespare/cp (from $GOROOT)
    /home/sam/work/blockchain/go-ethereum/build/_workspace/src/github.com/cespare/cp (from $GOPATH)
internal/build/pgp.go:27:2: cannot find package "golang.org/x/crypto/openpgp" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/golang.org/x/crypto/openpgp (from $GOROOT)
    /home/sam/work/blockchain/go-ethereum/build/_workspace/src/golang.org/x/crypto/openpgp (from $GOPATH)
common/types.go:31:2: cannot find package "golang.org/x/crypto/sha3" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/golang.org/x/crypto/sha3 (from $GOROOT)
    /home/sam/work/blockchain/go-ethereum/build/_workspace/src/golang.org/x/crypto/sha3 (from $GOPATH)
Makefile:20: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

So weird here because I follow the steps in the documents. Thanks for help.

Comment: Problem solved with the latest golang version.

Answer (score 2):

This issue has been resolved in golang 1.13 and above.